# How can I execute first @After void after() from junit and then @ExpectedDatabase from db-unit?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-test, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I want to test a database view and I use db-unit to insert data into tables which are used by tested view and expected values form view is done by db-unit, but this view use some data form another view which I want to mock, I have done some a script which replace view with mock data, after finishing test method mock view is replaced with original view

But I find a problem, `@ExpectedDatabase` is invoked after `@After void after()` method, and test fails.

**How can I execute first `@After void after()` from junit and then `@ExpectedDatabase` from db-unit?**

Here is my code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfigTest.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener. DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
public class ClassTest {

 private static final String MOCK_REOURCE_PATH = "classpath:sql/mock_view.sql";

 private static final String ORIGINAL_REOURCE_PATH = "classpath:sql/original_view.sql";

 @Autowired
 private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

 @Before
 public void init() {
   ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript((DataSource) applicationContext.getBean("dataSource").getConnection(), applicationContext.getReource(MOCK_REOURCE_PATH ));
 }

  @Test
  @DatabaseSetup("classpath:sample-data.xml")
  @ExpectedDatabase(assertionMode = NON_STRICT, value = "classpath:expected-data.xml")
  public void testView() {
  }

  @After
  public void after() {
   ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript((DataSource) applicationContext.getBean("dataSource").getConnection(), applicationContext.getReource(ORIGINAL_REOURCE_PATH ));
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `@Before` and `@After` with `@BeforeTransaction` and `@AfterTransaction`, respectively?

Comment: @SamBrannen I've tried, but the test still fails. I think the db unit has its own transaction which starts before the spring transaction

Comment: How are you configuring the DbUnit support? From the code you posted, it seems impossible that DbUnit is even executing.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration for `@TestExecutionListeners` is broken: it doesn't compile "as is".

Make sure you register the `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` **and** the `DbUnitTestExecutionListener` via `@TestExecutionListeners`, and annotate your test class with Spring's `@Transactional` annotation, something similar to the following...

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfigTest.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@Transactional
public class ClassTest { /* ... */ }
```